# Custom UI element in Swift: Subclassing CALayer and overriding drawInContext results in pixelated drawing

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, swift, calayer

I'm currently learning how to implement custom controls. I inevitably stumbled upon the CALayer possibility, as using UIImage is not flexible enough when complex animations need to be performed.

I want to use UIView as a "container" for a CALayer so that its width and height are always the same as the UIView (for flexibility purposes).

I subclassed CALayer and overwrote the drawInContext() method.

Here's the result I'm getting on screen:
[image: Fuzzy / Pixelated image]

The drawing looks pixelated and fuzzy. I am using PaintCode to generate the drawing code for me.

Here's the custom CALayer:

```
class SegmentActive: CALayer {

func frameSetup() -> CGRect {

    let frameWidth:CGFloat = superlayer.frame.width
    let frameHeight:CGFloat = superlayer.frame.height

    let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight)

    println("\(superlayer.frame.width) // \(superlayer.frame.height)")

    return frame

}

override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext!) {

    UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)

    CalorieCalculatorUI.drawSegControlActiveBase(frameSetup())

    UIGraphicsPopContext()

}
```

}

And here's how I use it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var leftSegmentUIView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let activeSegment:SegmentActive = SegmentActive()

    leftSegmentUIView.layer.addSublayer(activeSegment)

    activeSegment.frame = activeSegment.frameSetup()

    activeSegment.setNeedsDisplay()

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong here? :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You have to set `contentsScale` of the layer to something larger than the default 1.0.

---

The scale factor of a layer defaults to 1. This changes how large the content buffer for that layer is:

> Applies to [...] and content provided via `-drawInContext:` (i.e. if `contentsScale` is two `-drawInContext:` will draw into a buffer twice as large as the layer bounds)

Since you are doing custom drawing into context that has fewer pixels than the devices screen, the drawing looks pixelated. For traditional "retina" screens, the scale factor you are expecting is `2.0` but with the recent introduction of the iPhone 6+ there is also the scale factor of `3.0`. The good news is that you can get the device scale from `UIScreen`.

Comment: Thank you so much David! You're an absolute legend! Your answers and blogs are always crammed with knowledge and wisdom. Once again - thank you kind Sir!

Comment: Indeed.  Just FTR a common, similar, related problems is that when you (say) animate the size of something like that, you need to self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

Comment: Hey @JoeBlow, thank you! I indeed plan to animate a lot of stuff so I'm sure that would come in handy.

Comment: I really hope it helps.  I have wasted hours by forgetting that, at times!!